# VSCode terminal process command failed to launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, npm-run

I am trying out the [Hello World sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/helloworld-sample) extension. But when I run the extension from the 'Run Extension' task. It gives the following error:

```
The terminal process command '/bin/zsh -c 'npm run watch'' failed to launch (exit code: 127)
```

But I am able to run the above command from terminal without any errors.

Comment: I'm seeing this also, but with `/bin/bash` (which is my shell). I suspect that the `-l` flag is supposed to be passed to the shell so that it becomes a "login shell" and loads settings from `.profile`. The command is coming from the `.vscode/tasks.json` file where the first task is of type "npm" and script "watch".

Answer (score 6):

Just found this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76542 For me in OSX apparently is an issue when opening code from the terminal with `code .` and can be fixed by checking in settings Terminal>Integrated: Inherit Evn to inherit the environment from VSCode

Comment: I have inherit env checked, but the issue still persists for me.

Answer (score 2):

If macOS and your computer recently *restarted on its own* (e.g., kernel panic), I found that VScode reloads improperly without loading the environment in all Terminals that were open prior.

**The fix is simply to close out of VSCode completely, then relaunch**. The environments will then load properly.