# VSCode - Starting debugging for an extension gives process terminated error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I followed the [VSCode extension development guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to create a new extension project.
Starting debugging for the extension gave - 
`The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'npm run watch'" terminated with exit code: 1.`

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194964/vscode-terminal-process-command-failed-to-launch) seems related, but I do have `Inherit Env` checked under `Terminal>Integrated` in settings as mentioned in the answer. 
Also I am on mac os.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add

```
"watch": {
        "files": "**/*.ts"
    },
```

in the `package.json` file, at the same level as "scripts", based on the [npm-watch documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-watch).